# Java Filenotfound exception being thrown

Tags: java, io, filenotfoundexception

A FileNotFound Exception is being thrown for my code even though I have the file in the exact directory I stated. I have also tried `...new File("euler8.txt");...` with no success. My code is as follows:

```
        private static void euler8() throws IOException
{   
    int current;
    int largest=0;
    int c =0;
    ArrayList<Integer> bar = new ArrayList<Integer>(0);
    File infile = new File("C:/Users/xxxxxxxx/workspace/Euler1/euler8.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream(infile),
            Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    try
    {
        while((c = reader.read()) != -1) 
        {
            bar.add(c);
        }
    }
    finally{reader.close();}
    for(int i=0; i<bar.size(); i++)
    {
        current = bar.get(i) * bar.get(i+1) * bar.get(i+2) * bar.get(i+3) * bar.get(i+4);
        if(largest<current)
            largest = current;
    }
}
```

Image of what it is doing:

http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/7017/halpbk.png

Comment: Have you tried printing the absolute path of your file, and possibly compare that output to the absolute path of new File(".") to see if you made any mistakes in the path? Is the case correct in the file name?

Comment: Try adding `System.out.println(infile.exists());` right after you declare `infile`.  If that comes back false, something is wrong with your file path - keep going back a directory till you get true.  If it comes back true... ???

Comment: Try to use `../Euler1/euler8.txt` as your file path.

Comment: `../Euler1/euler8.txt` did not work. Same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except for everything else that has been suggested, you could check whether you're having this issue (which we've been seeing in our lab): Files with twice the extension. In other words, make sure your `euler8.txt` is really called that and not `euler8.txt.txt`, for instance, because, with hidden extensions, the file explorer will show the first but it may not strike you as odd initially, if you don't remember that it's supposed to hide the extension.

Comment: From the picture given by @James Roberts, I think you are right. The file name shows 'euler8.txt' but it should have shown only 'euler8', because the extension is specified separately in Windows 7.

Comment: @JavaNewbie_M107 I hadn't noticed the picture. That seems to be it. Let's hope OP checks back here.

Comment: To help... On my development Windows machines, I turn that option off, because this issue gets me frequently with the easy method of renaming files in Windows, but the lack of visibility of the extension.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis WINNER

Answer (score 2):

Forward slashes work fine, and are preferred because they work on any platform (relative paths are better than absolute).  Make sure your path exists as specified, and verify that you have read access on the directories leading to the file.  For example, if you're running your java program as a different user, you may not have read access on the "myuser" folder.

Answer (score 1):

This code will not work if all of the directories do not yet exist as well, so I'd assume (hopefully I am correct) that you have a typo, or are missing a folder.

I usually prefer to have a `java.io.File` reference to the parent directory, then use it as parent in a subsequent file reference, i.e.:

```
File dir = new File("parentDir");
File inFile = new File(dir, "fileName");
```

Also, `java.io.File` has an `exists()` method that returns true or false, and its subsequent `mkdir()`,`mkdirs()`, and `createNewFile()` return true or false if they actually create the requested file.

That said, I modified your code to the following, and it executes on my machine; but I do not know what data you are trying to run through this.

```
    int current;
    int largest = 0;
    int c = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> bar = new ArrayList<Integer>(0);
    File dir = new File("C:/Users/myuser/workspace/Euler1");
    if(!dir.exists()){
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    File infile = new File(dir, "euler8.txt");
    if(!infile.exists()){
        infile.createNewFile();
    }
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream(infile),
            Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    try {
        while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
            bar.add(c);
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < bar.size(); i++) {
        current = bar.get(i) * bar.get(i + 1) * bar.get(i + 2) * bar.get(i + 3) * bar.get(i + 4);
        if (largest < current) {
            largest = current;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The backslashes are quite unnecessary. I ran this program:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File infile = new File("C:/Users/pats/workspace/test/euler8.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(infile), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    try {
      String s;
      while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
      }
    } finally {
      reader.close();
    }
  }
}
```

which is very similar, and it printed the contents of my file.

I think you need to check both that the file exists, and that you have access to it.